# Opposite of WHERE IN SQlite with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I try to make a sharing function in my PHP application.
Every User has an ID and can read his own project and should read the projects, where his ID is in the `can_read_by` array.

```
project_id  user_id     can_read_by
1           7           2,3,4
2           6           3
3           2           5
4           1           2
5           5           3,1
```

How do i, to serve the user 2 the projects: 1, 3 and 4?

### edit:

new question: [Get many Id`s with WHERE in SQlite with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71904111/get-many-ids-with-where-in-sqlite-with-php)

Comment: Ideally you would normalise your data such that you have a dedicated table with a FK for project_id and a user_id column, then your query becomes both simpler and more performant.

Comment: Ideally, when you denormalize that way, you would not use a comma-separated list of integers but a list of quoted integers so you can easily access them (old-school) or you would program against proprietary / relatively new JSON Text access and use an array of integers as JSON Text and the JSON Text functions to handle the data your DB server offers [mind the gap what a number in JSON is(!)].

Comment: @Stu , can you give me more information, or an example about the dedicated table? Because performance is a good reason.

Comment: Opposite of `IN` would be `NOT IN`, to answer your subject line. However you can't use either of them on comma-separated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the operator `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE user_id = ?
   OR ',' || can_read_by || ',' LIKE '%,' || ? || ',%';
```

Change `?` with the user's id that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1c7b7ee8d483d9ae15ce19700a0e309a).